# Trying to run an awk command on each line in a file, and replace the current line with the results of the awk

Tags: bash, awk, while-loop

I am trying to cycle through a file, and use each line to search a different csv file (specifically searching the 2nd column) and return the 4th column in that file for each entry. I then want to replace the current line with the new result. The input file looks like this:

```
Ant
Bat
Carp
Dog
```

At the moment I am using this code:

```
while read -r line
do
awk -v line="\"$line\"" -F, '$2 ~ line' search.csv | awk -F, '{print $4}' >> $filename
done < $filename
```

This adds the new line onto the end of the file and so I get this output:

```
Ant
Bat
Carp
Dog
"Insect"
"Mammal"
"Fish"
"Mammal"
```

How do I get just the second list (the words in quotes)?

---

Edited:

Here is sample data from search.csv:

```
"A0001","Dog","Canine","Mammal","4","Y","N"
```

---

Update#1

The search.csv file has each entry in quotes. I have edited my awk like this:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {wrds["\""$1"\""]; next} $2 in wrds {print ($4 > "temporary.txt")}' "filename.txt" search.csv
```

And now it prints a 0 for each line to the screen instead. The temporary.txt file is still empty:

```
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: please update the question with a sample set of 4-6 lines from `search.csv`; also provide the expected result (making sure it corresponds to the provided samples)

Comment: the `while/read` loop is reading *from* the file `$filename` while the dual `awk` scripts are appending *to* the same file `$filename`; but then you state you only want to see the quoted words in the output; do you really want to append to `$filename`, overwrite `$filename`, or save the output to a completely different file?

Comment: @markp-fuso Oh actually this makes more sense. I have tried this and it does work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at OP's latest code attempt:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {wrds["\""$1"\""]; next} $2 in wrds {print ($4 > "temporary.txt")}' "filename.txt" search.csv
```

OP states this generates a `0` at the terminal and `temporary.txt` is empty. **NOTE:** When I run OP's code it does generate a `0` at the console but it doesn't even create a file named `temporary.txt`.

The primary issue is with the following:

```
print ($4 > "temporary.txt")
```

Where:

- contents of the parens are processed first, so ...
- `($4 > "temporary.txt")` is processed as a comparison/conditional, ie, comparing the 4th field to see if it's 'greater than' the literal string `"temporary.txt"`
- in this case `$4 == "Mammal"` and `awk` says `"Mammal"` is not `> "temporary.txt"` so the result is 'false', which in `awk` is represented by a `0`, so ...
- the `print` sends a `0` (aka 'false') to the console ...
- and, of course, nothing is ever written to any file (ie, the file named `temporary.txt` is not created let alone written to)

The quick fix is to remove the parens so that the `print` sends `$4` to a file named `temporary.txt`, ie:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR {wrds["\""$1"\""]; next} $2 in wrds {print $4 > "temporary.txt"}' "filename.txt" search.csv
$              <<=== no ouput, no '0'
$ cat temporary.txt
"Mammal
```

---

The method of designating the name of the output file, from within the `awk` script, is typically used when you want the `awk` script to send output to a dynamically generated set, or variable number, of output files.

In this case since all output is going to the same `temporary.txt` file, the typical approach is to define the output file on the command line (ie, outside of the `awk` script); this tends to make the `awk` script a bit cleaner, eg:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {wrds["\""$1"\""]; next} $2 in wrds {print $4}' filename.txt search.csv > temporary.txt
                                                      ^^^^^^^^                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a shell loop. Just do this in a single awk command like this:

```bash
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {wrds["\"" $1 "\""]; next}
$2 in wrds {print $4 > "tmpFile"}' "$filename" search.csv
```

Manually verify output in `tmpFile` and once you're satisfied run:

```
mv tmpFile "$filename"
```

to replace original input file.

Comment: I have tried this command and it doesn't do anything. There is no output and the tmpfile is empty: awk -F, 'NR==FNR{wrds[$1];next}$2 in wrds{print ($4 > "tmpfile")}' filename.txt search.csv

Comment: Provide sample data from your `search.csv` by editing your question

Comment: @JJRudder, make sure your files do not have DOS-style `\r\n` line endings

Comment: Also be vary of quoted cell values. If csv file has `"Dog"` then change this `awk` to `NR==FNR {wrds["\"" $1 "\""]; next}`

Comment: @JJRudder: Try my updated answer now.